# react jsx render using map

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm developing an application using React JS and JSX. It is kind of On the Job Training. One thing I noticed is, I get the same result for two different types of code. I would like to understand more about this. Can someone explain this, please?

**Code Block one**

```
{
    this.state.entities.map((entity, index) => {
        return <Link key={index} to={{ pathname: '/details/'}}>{entity.main_question}</Link>
    })
}
```

**Code Block two**

```
{
    this.state.entities.map((entity, index) => (
        <Link key={index} to={{ pathname: '/details/' }}>{entity.main_question}</Link>
    ))
}
```

Comment: Because in essence it's the same: the `()` within the map returns the component, whereas the `{}` allows you to add additional code before you return the component.

Comment: It's because you can *implicitly* return values with arrow functions, see @BoyWithSilverWings comment link

Answer (score 0):

The map function of javascript loops through array of objects and return the value for each iteration.

Example:
In normal JS,

```
const arr=[1,2,3,4,5];
const squared=arr.map(function(value){return value*value})//squared=[1,4,9,16,25]
```

Now in arrow functions you can write the callback as follows

```
const squared=arr.map((value)=>value*value)//This is same as return value*value in the function body.
```

Answer (score 0):

about code block one :

when you use `=> {}` curly braces you have to use `return`

```
{
    array.map((item, index) => {
        return something
    })
}
```

code block two :

when you use `=> ()` it will direct return the expression or component , no need to add return here

```
 {
        array.map((item, index) => ( something ))
 }
```

now question arrives in your mind when to use which one :

generally when you have some if conditions use code block 1 :

```
{
        array.map((item, index) => {
            if(some_codition_here){
              return something;
            }else{
              return something_else;
            }
        })
}
```

if there is no conditions you can use code block 2 .

Answer (score 0):

The answer is there in the code itself

In this case, you are using = {} So you have to write the keyword `return`

```
{
    this.state.entities.map((entity, index) => {
        return <Link key={index} to={{ pathname: '/details/'}}>{entity.main_question}</Link>
    })
}
```

In this case, you are using = () , So you don't have to use `return`

```
{
    this.state.entities.map((entity, index) => (
        <Link key={index} to={{ pathname: '/details/' }}>{entity.main_question}</Link>
    ))
}
```

Because it is a new feature in ES6, It is basically like writing in a single line without